# How to get the WHMCS root directory

Tags: php, whmcs

I have made a simple WHMCS add on that uses the hook function in WHMCS.
It works fine on my installation if I use `require_once (ROOTDIR.'/modules/addons/module_name/modulefunction.php')` because I use a sub domain for my WHMCS. But i tested it on another installation which does not use a sub domain and not it does not work, because the WHMCS directory is not included in the name.

Is there any way for me to get the name of the directory or just go from the hooks folder (`includes/hooks/my_hook.php`) backwards to the addons directory.

I tried using `require_once '../../../modules/addons/module_name/modulefunction.php';` but it just says it cannot find the file.

Error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../../../modules/addons/module_name/modulefunction.php' (include_path='/home/me/public_html/hosting/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php/') in /home/me/public_html/hosting/includes/hooks/my_hook.php on line 55
```

Any assistance would be great :).
Thank you.

Comment: You actually could calculate the absolute url by looking at the document root and absolute path. I don't know if there is a build in method to get that.

Comment: Hi @fleuv i am not sure what you mean. How will i get the folder using that. And if it does work. How will i know when it is in a sub domain then and thus have no folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the includes/hooks folder, couldn't you just do:

```
require_once dirname( dirname( __DIR__ ) ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'modules' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'addons' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'module_name' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'modulefunction.php';
```

I believe the double dirname on the DIR will get you into the root regardless of your installation.

Comment: I did follow this path at the end of the day... Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

**Posting this as I could not find an answer for this anywhere.**

I wanted to do a sanity check on my WHMCS addon to make sure that other files were installed, so I did the code below and works perfectly.

I load this BEFORE any other file in the module so there are zero dependencies on anything else in relation to the module.

This code is in {whmcs–dir}/modules/servers/mailtrust.php

So as soon as I go to any page in my module, it will make sure all the necessary files are installed and if not throw a friendly error.

$path_to_includes will give you the directory where your module is installed within the current WHMCS install.

```
$path_to_includes =  dirname( dirname( __DIR__ ) );
$path_to_includes =  str_replace("modules","includes", $path_to_includes);
$path_to_includes = $path_to_includes . "/hooks/mailtrust.php";
if(!file_exists($path_to_includes)) {
   echo "<h1>ERROR - System File Missing</h1>";
   echo "Please upload the mailtrust hook file to $path_to_includes";
   exit;
}
```